# How to divide activity to two page/layouts as in viewpager?

Tags: android

I have an application with a single page. But I want to create another page for an information from the file that I fill up using background service. I want it look like as swipable tabs. What is the best option to do it ?

I have only 1 Activity and 1 service. Service is just for getting information from web and saving it to file. First page is for controls, second, which I want to add, is for ListView that will read from that file service is filling up (swipable tabs will be the best). I tried to use Fragments, but there is too much to rewrite in order to transfer logic to Fragment.

Comment: Use a tab layout with a view pager.

Comment: post your design here

Comment: Use a `ViewPager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Best option is to use ViewPager and Fragments as the UI codes will be clean and will easily be obtained from internet.

The other option if you are not willing to rewrite the code is to use a Tabbed View and clicking on the tab will hide and show elements in the mainlayout( Will not have animations though)